# What is the numpy equivalent of [M, I] = min(____)

Tags: python, numpy, matlab, min

I have this matlab code that I am trying to convert to python:

```
M = 100
K = 40
for m=1:M
  for k=1:K
    [dist(m,k),index] = min([norm(AP(m,:,1)-Ter(k,:,1)), norm(AP(m,:,2) Ter(k,:,1)),norm(AP(m,:,3)-Ter(k,:,1))]);
    if dist(m,k)<d0
    betadB=-L - 35*log10(d1) + 20*log10(d1) - 20*log10(d0);
    end
    elseif ((dist(m,k)>=d0) && (dist(m,k)<=d1))
    betadB= -L - 35*log10(d1) + 20*log10(d1) - 20*log10(dist(m,k));
    else
    betadB = -L - 35*log10(dist(m,k)) + Z_shd(m,k); %large-scale in dB
    end
            
    BETAA(m,k)=10^(betadB/10); 
    
   end
end
```

From this, betadB is a single value (-136.48). Here's what I have done:

```
    for m in range(M):
        for k in range(K):
            dist[m,k] = np.nanmin(np.array(
                [np.linalg.norm(AP[0,m,:] - Ter[0,k,:],2),
                 np.linalg.norm(AP[1,m,:] - Ter[0,k,:],2),
                 np.linalg.norm(AP[2,m,:] - Ter[0,k,:],2)]))
            
            if dist[m,k] < d0:
                betadB = -L - 35*np.log10(d1) + 20*np.log10(d1) - 20*np.log10(d0);
            elif ((dist[m,k] >= d0) and (dist[m,k] <= d1)):
                betadB = -L - 35*np.log10(d1) + 20*np.log10(d1) - 20*np.log10(dist[m,k])
            else:
                betadB = - L - 35*np.log10(dist[m,k]) + Z_shd[m,k]

The dimension for betadB in my case is (40,40).
```

In the documentation, I saw this: *[M,I] = min(___) also returns the index into the operating dimension that corresponds to the minimum value of A for any of the previous syntaxes.* Since ideally i need just dist[m,k], I ignored index.

Can someone help me with an idea on how to convert this? Many thanks

Comment: You haven't explained what you think is wrong with what you have done.

Comment: One slight simplification you can make is rewriting `dist[m,k] = np.min(np.linalg.norm(AP[:,m,:] - Ter[0,k,:],axis=1))`

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser , Thanks for your reply. I am getting a different dimension/shape for betadB in my python code.

Comment: The subject line makes it sound like the issue is the MATLAB min.  `numpy` has a `min` and `argmin`.  But since you aren't using `index` you don't need `argmin`.  If you code runs, but give wrong values, then you need to focus on that, not on this `min` function.  Generally when translating code like this, I like to test both line by line, with a special focus on shapes.  You need to know/verify the dimensions at each step.